# Initialize generic object from a System.Type

Tags: c#, generics

I need to create a generic type, but I do not know the type at compile time. I would like to do this:

```
Type t = typeof(whatever);
var list = new List<t>
```

this won't compile, because t is not a valid type. But it does know all about a valid type. Is there a way to dynamically create the generic list from a System.Type like this? I may need reflection, and that's ok, I am just a bit lost here.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Like this:

```
Type t;
Type genericListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t);
object list = Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType);
```

Note that you can only assign it to a variable of type `object`.  (Although you can cast to to the non-generic `IList` interface)

To use the `list` variable, you'll probably need reflection.

Comment: This works great, except it is a pain to use afterward. Gets the job done though.

Comment: Correct; it's a pain to use.  There may be better options; you can ask another question here and tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: Turns out in my application of this, I can quite easily cast it to a nongeneric interface and it works quite well.