# Using methods of an object without casting

Tags: c#, reflection, types, casting, generics

I have a problem with casting/types and so on.

Firstly, my query is a follow on from another post here:
[Initialize generic object from a System.Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831622/initialize-generic-object-from-a-system-type)

so to continue on from this question, how can I use the methods of my newly created object?

i.e. what I want to do is as follows:

```
Type iFace = typeof(IService1);
Type genericListType = typeof(System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<>).MakeGenericType(iFace);
object factory = Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType, new object[]
                    {
                        new BasicHttpBinding(),
                        new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:1693/Service.svc")
                    });
var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
```

by the way, although I am using this application for WCF, this is not a WCF problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a [dynamic object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)? This allows you to call methods that might or might not exist.

Comment: Glad I could provide an answer! (wink wink ;)

Answer (score 2):

Without dynamic objects:

```
object factory = Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType, new object[]
{
    new BasicHttpBinding(),
    new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:1693/Service.svc")
});

Type factoryType = factory.GetType();
MethodInfo methodInfo = factoryType.GetMethod("CreateChannel");
var channel = methodInfo.Invoke(factory) as YourChannelType;
```